# PHP can't login to MySQL server?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, centos

I have this `client.php` file in `Server A` which will use database server `Server B`. Both CentOS.

I have installed all the necessary services such as php, phpmyadmin, mysql on both servers and at first, I encountered this issue *`"reading initial communication packets, lost connection to SQL"`* when I login using my php file and as I researched, i needed to run following commands.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db=1
```

After running those commands, the error message doesn't appear anymore but it doesn't log in at all.. It is stuck in the login page.

Do I have to allow some features for php to be able to work with mysql in centos remotely? Please kindly help out as Im a newbie in Linux.

Comment: Can you login from the commandline? `you@server-a> mysql -u your-user -p -h server-b`

Comment: There needs to be more information before anyone can provide you an answer that's more than speculation.  What does your PHP login code look like, for example does it detect and report errors on failure?  Have you tried logging into the MySQL server using the MySQL commandline client or some other MySQL client from the PHP computer?  What firewall settings or other intrusion prevention mechanisms are configured on the MySQL and PHP machines?

Comment: You first need to check if you can login using command line as Jony's suggestion above. If yes, then you can proceed to config mysql to allow connections from other machines from network as it only allows local connections only, by default.

Just check the login by command line first then let me know.